# How is HTTP Header set in Spring RestTemplate?

Tags: java, json, spring, tomcat

I wanted to get the plain string, not JSON. The code at client side:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("", headers);
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

ResponseEntity<String> tickerResponse = restTemplate.exchange(serviceBase, HttpMethod.GET, entity,String.class);
```

It works well in local unit test. The log looks like:

> 08:24:46,291 DEBUG RestTemplate:598 - Setting request Accept header to
>   [text/plain, */*]

However, it doesn't work in tomcat, the log was:

> 08:20:48,362 DEBUG RestTemplate:598 - Setting request Accept header
>   to [application/json, application/*+json, text/plain, */*]

I guess RestTemplate set the Accept Header to JSON by default when running in my Tomcat 8. How to clean the default settings?

Comment: Some code is missing to be able to answer the question: Can you add the relevant parts of the class + additional parts of the function?

Comment: These are all before making a remote call by calling "exchange" method. The only thing I didn't post here was:

·
MainDriver.resetCnMessageConverter(restTemplate);
·
in the above function I have code to handle char sets which is not relevant I guess.